# Does liquid coming up to the throat invalidate one's fast?

Tags: ramadan, sawm

If liquid comes to the throat and you are lying down and swallow it, does it break one's fast?  Please answer with references.

Comment: What kind of liquid,if you could elaborate it

Answer (score 1):

If it's involuntary and you didn't mean it the no you haven't broken your fast

But if you did mean too, yes your fast has been broken